# How should the interval between serial dilutions be expressed?

Tags: experimental-design

The interval between simple dilutions is a constant value added to the preceding dilution to get the next. How should a factor for serial dilutions be mentioned? As there is no common difference between successive serial dilutions, rather a common ratio.

Comment: That depends strongly on your experimental needs. Sometimes 1:10 between two steps is necessary, sometimes 1:100 fits better.

Comment: I apologise, but I actually meant to ask how would you mention the interval. Like, interval for a simple dilution is 2% so how would the interval be stated for a serial dilution with concentration reduction by 1/10th every successive dilution?